# replace starting numerical digits

Tags: command-line, sed

I have content as given below.

```
2                                        -
2                                       1.0
2 10.
2 11.
2 12. Groover MP, Fundamentos de Manufactura Moderna, Tercera ed., Mc Graw Hill, México DF, 2007, pp.
```

I want to replace numerical digits starting of the line.
my expected output as below. using sed command.

```
2::                                        -
2::                                       1.0
2::10.
2::11.
2::12. Groover MP, Fundamentos de Manufactura Moderna, Tercera ed., Mc Graw Hill, México DF, 2007, pp.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this:

```
sed -i 's/^2\ /2::/' file.txt
```

This will replace the beginning of each line `2` with `2::` and writing it back into the input file.

Answer (score 1):

I get the things done by using following command. I want to replace 1st space with ::

command that I have used is as givevn below

```
sed 's/ /::/' filename >outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/::/'
```

This will replace the first whitespace in each line with `::`